# Ключ как значение

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Как получить ключ объекта или массива как значение по-мимо конструкции `for...in` и метода `Object.keys()`?

Comment: возможно [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) подойдёт

Comment: @diraria подходит, а но вы не подскажите как этот метод получает эти значения? может есть аналогичный способ на подобии `var a = {test: 2}; console.log(a.test);`.

Comment: думаю перебирает все ключи с помощью `for...in`, добавляет их в массив и возвращает этот массив. Если подробнее, то [вот код полифилла](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill).

Comment: @diraria по мимо `for...in` и `Object.keys`.

Comment: например ещё подходит вариант [`Object.entries(объект).map(entry => etnry[0])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), но скорее всего вам он тоже не понравится...

Comment: @diraria мне все нравиться, просто интересно как методы получают эти значения.

Comment: вроде это зависит от реализации javascript рантайма (ну и код там будет не на javascript, а на C++/...), например в v8 [вот так](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/v8/src/builtins/builtins-object-gen.cc#L113-L195)

Comment: @diraria можете теперь из этого составить ответ что бы я его отметил. спасибо, вы мне помогли.